# Timeout after field goal: when can it be taken?

Tags: basketball, fiba

What is the FIBA rule about taking a timeout after a field goal is made, with no fouls or violations other official intervention?

**EDIT added**: I have already read the rules, and in my view they are unclear.

**18.2.3.** A time-out opportunity begins when:

- For both teams, the ball becomes dead, the game clock is stopped and the official has ended his communication with the scorer's table.
- For both teams, the ball becomes dead following a successful last or only free throw.
- **For the non-scoring team, a field goal is scored.**

***Why is 18.2.8 rule there?***
18.2.8 would imply  that for the scoring team somehow timeout was possible after scoring without official interruption otherwise a special case for the last 2 minutes isnt needed. 18.2.8 doesnt seem to be a refinement of  18.2.3 It appears to contradict it.

> 18.2.8. A time-out shall not be permitted to the scoring team when the game clock shows 2:00 minutes or less in the fourth period and in each
>   extra period and, following a successful field goal unless an official
>   has interrupted the game.

even harder to understand

> 18.2.3  (...) For both teams, the ball becomes dead

how is the ball not dead for both teams ? Art 10 doesnt say anything about dead for 1 and alive for another.

> 10.1. The ball can be either live or dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the ball is dead, yes, but the first line says:

> For both teams, the ball becomes dead, the game clock is stopped and the official has ended his communication with the scorer's table.

That is "and".  The ball is dead AND the clock is stopped.  The clock does not stop following a field goal, outside the last two minutes (Rule 49.2), so the team that made the shot cannot call time out.  That's consistent with general play, after all; a team normally can call timeout whenever it possesses the ball.  Making a shot hands possession to the other team.

Now, yes, after the last 2 minutes in the fourth or subsequent period, it does stop following a made field goal.  Thus, the additional clarification point:

> A time-out shall not be permitted to the scoring team when the game clock shows
>   2:00 minutes or less in the fourth period and in each extra period and, following a
>   successful field goal unless an official has interrupted the game.

This follows the initial rule, so it is intended to modify or limit that rule.  In this case, the initial rule is clearly intended to read that a team may not call timeout after making a basket; before the 'last two minutes' clock stoppage was added (sometime in the last couple of decades I believe), that was sufficient.  Once that rule was added, a clarification was needed to make it clear that it is not intended for a team to be able to call timeout after making a shot *even if* the clock stops, unless there is a separate interruption.

Comment: Thanks Joe, That was the explanation I was looking for. `49.2` with the `and the clock is stopped`  Appreciate you clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

The timeout rule is pretty simple:

> 18.2.2. A time-out may be granted during a time-out opportunity.
>
> 18.2.3. A time-out opportunity begins when:
>
> - For both teams, the ball becomes dead, the game clock is stopped and the official has ended his communication with the scorer's table.
> - For both teams, the ball becomes dead following a successful last or only free throw.
> - For the non-scoring team, a field goal is scored.

So regarding your question in case a field goal is scored the non-scoring team only can get a timeout.

[Source](https://www.fiba.com/downloads/Rules/2014/Official_Basketball_Rules_2014_Y.pdf).

Comment: Hey, Dor, thanks for the reply, I updated my question to reflect in more detail what I see as the problem. What is 18.2.8 all about and why do we talk about dead for both teams. ?